# .net office automation project protected issue

Tags: .net, vba, office-interop, office-automation

I'm opening up an excel file which is project protected ie. I can't add a vba module to it.

But I need to execute a vba module on this file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, copy all sheets to a new instance of workbook and then apply macro on that.!

Answer (score 0):

Answers here, which could be translated to .net:

[How do I remove the password from a VBA project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/excel-vba-project-password-removal)

Tim

Comment: I don't want to crack the password. May be add macro as addin? or copy the file to another file without protection? I would like to know about these options and how to implement/

Comment: @WhoIs: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "execute a VBA module on this file", so maybe you could expand on that?  I took it to mean you wanted to inseret some code into the VB project, but maybe you meant something else ?