# How do I write to SQL table using excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have a SQL table called Audit. There are two fields in this table called UN and CN. My server name is analive and DB is DW_ALL. I am trying to capture in excel the username and computer name that accesses/opens my workbook or sheet then write that audit information to my SQL table.

```
Sub UpdateTable()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strDate As Date

strText = ActiveSheet.Range("b4").Value
''strDate = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")''

Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
        "Data Source=icl-analive; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=DW_ALL;" & _
        "User ID=ccataldo;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

cnn.Open cnnstr

''uSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_ExcelUpdate (CellText,CellDate) VALUES ('" & strText & "', " & strDate & ")"''
''uSQL = "INSERT INTO Audit (UN,CN) VALUES (MsgBox Environ("username"), MsgBox         Environ("username""''
uSQL = INSERT INTO Audit (UN,CN) VALUES ('MsgBox Environ("username") ', 'MsgBox Environ("username"'))

Debug.Print uSQL

cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Re-reading your post; I'm no longer sure I've correctly understood your issue.  Can you post the error code, and tell us which line is responsible.

Comment: What is the error?  Are you not going to be needing to hard code a user/pass if the workbook is to be shared with others?  If so, don't forget to lock out the macros so they aren't readable -- but that's not unbreakable!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/how-do-i-remove-the-password-from-a-vba-project

Comment: Also, your best bet would be to create a sql account to use, and give it NO permissions, except execute on a stored proc which does the insert for you.

Answer (score 0):

Connection strings can be tricky things.  I rely heavily on [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/) to refresh my memory.

Trusted_Connection and User ID are mutually exclusive.  Use trusted connection when you want to log onto SQL Server using your Windows account.  Username and password are for logging in with a [SQL account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Assuming you want to use your Windows login; try this:

`Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=analive;Database=DW_ALL;Trusted_Connection=yes;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script that writes to an AccessDB. The SQL Should be similar as well as the needed vba statements. I hope it helps

Also it uses DAO and not Addob connection type.

```
Private Sub thisbetheshitmane()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tb As DAO.TableDef
    Dim vAr As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim InCombined As Boolean
    Dim InOpen As Boolean
    Dim vbSql As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

    StartTime = Timer

    Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\dzcoats\Documents\Microsoft.accdb")

    For Each tb In db.TableDefs
        If Len(tb.Connect) > 0 Then
            tb.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next tb     

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Table_Name].Defect FROM [Table_Name] WHERE [Table_Name].Defect IS NOT NULL;")

    Dim QResult() As Variant
    QResult = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)
    For a = LBound(QResult, 2) To UBound(QResult, 2)
        vAr = QResult(0, a)
    Next a

    For y = LBound(QResult, 2) To UBound(QResult, 2)
        If vAr <> "Defect" And vAr <> vbNullString And vAr <> "" Then

            If InCombined = True And InOpen = True Then
                vbSql = "UPDATE [Table_Name] SET [Table_Name].Status ='Bad Defect Number' WHERE ((([Table_Name].Defect)='" & vAr & "'));"
                db.Execute vbSql
            End If

            If InCombined = False And InOpen = True Then
                vbSql = "UPDATE [Table_Name] SET [Table_Name].Status ='Completed' WHERE ((([Table_Name].Defect)='" & vAr & "'));"
                db.Execute vbSql
            End If

        End If
    Next y

    rst.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```