# Save protected pdf as unprotected pdf file

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I could open protected pdf file by vba, but everytime I open the file I still need password for it. Is there a way I could remove encrypted part by vba?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/removing-the-password-from-a-vba-project

Comment: You cannot use VBA to remove the password from a PDF file. The link above is for removing a password from a VBA project, and will not help you.

Comment: What can I do to remove the password? M