# Remove password protection of a VBA Module with a known password

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

It needs to perform a macro that would unprotect the VBA Modules within the xlsb file. Then execute some code, then it would need to re-protect the VBA modules with the same password.

Tried these methods: [Removing the password from a VBA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/removing-the-password-from-a-vba-project)

Comment: What problem did you run into with those suggestions?

Comment: Is this a repeat question that was asked a few hours ago? Seems like I have recently read it earlier.