# So my Excel-VBA project password can easily be cracked... What are other options?

Tags: vba, excel, passwords, password-protection

Now that I know that there is an [easy workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project) to the [standard way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165442(office.10).aspx) of locking and password-protecting VBA code, I'd like to move on to more effective ways of protecting code. I am to deliver an Excel-based tool to a client, but would like something more than simple annoyance-type protection that will only deter the laziest of hackers.

Are there any options in Excel-VBA, or do we really have to compile a separate application and forget about our Excel-based interface?

Comment: If you are looking for VBA obfuscater, I'd suggest checking out a tool call VBASH. IMHO it is better than CrunchCode and Obfu-VBA, and definitely better than password protection. https://www.ayedeal.com/vbash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest and most efficient way is to move your VBA code to a VB6 compiled Com/automation addin.

Or you may want to consider a .Net (with obfuscator) solution if performance is not important.

Comment: +1. I was going to use the com approach when I looked at varrious methods of protecting an addin I considered commercialising. It was clearly the most secure option. And I second that obfuscation can be very effective

Answer (score 4):

Practically, **VBA obfuscators** do not protect VBA code because they leave the structure of the algorithm unchanged, which can be traced back to the original algorithms which can then be recovered.

Converting your **VBA code to VB6** means your application will be limited to 32bit Excel (VB6 doesn’t have a 64-bit version) and it can be decompiled by VB decompilers such as https://www.vb-decompiler.org/

Converting your **VBA code to VB.NET** isn't a perfect solution either, as .NET has a ‘reflection’ mechanism which can convert the compiled code of .NET assembly into the original source code.

You can convert your **VBA code to C/C++**, which would be a very effective form of protection, but since C/C++ and VBA are very different programming languages, the conversion of VBA code to C/C++ is difficult, error prone, and generally not worth the huge amount of time and effort that it takes.

There is a tool called **VbaCompiler for Excel** (http://vbacompiler.com) which converts the **VBA code to C language code and then compiles it into a DLL**. The level of protection this tool claims to provide is similar to that of converting your VBA code to C/C++ but without the massive amount of manual work that is required for such a process.

Answer (score 2):

Another Trick is to write the code against a excel object in Access then make the access file in to a .mde
http://www.blog.methodsinexcel.co.uk/?s=Access+MDB
Poor, but cheep ;-)

Comment: The given link is broken, try this http://www.databasedev.co.uk/microsoft-access-mde.html.  Looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

No need to convert to another language - you should be able to obfuscate most of your VBA code through [www.vbsobfuscator.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20120608081754/http://vbsobfuscator.com/) [Note: Links to archive.org]

Comment: This is now a dead Link taken over by a site squatter with dubious website links.

Comment: I could not find a current version, so I edited the post to link to the most recent working archive.org copy of the site. I did not test that the actual obfuscator feature of the site still works, however.