# Locked excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet from third party in which the VBA is password protected. I could not add any additionally code to the VBA editor sheet.

I need functionality like this :

I have three cells with value of 'true'. I would like to change these three cells to 'false' with a single click. (Basically I need some emergency functionality in which I could turn all the cells to false with a single click).

How could I work around that without the VBA?

Comment: To incorporate that functionality you will have to get the password for the 3rd party app. Ethically, hacking the password for a 3rd party app is not right. Imagine if someone does that to your application? I would recommend getting in touch with the 3rd party and asking them for the password or requesting them to incorporate the functionality that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that requires buttons and actions on click events will require some VBA unfortunately.

However, if your workbook is in the "old" .xls format (2003 and earlier versions - if it's not, I think you can just `Save As...` using `97-2003`) you may be able to remove the VBA password using a Hex editor. You can't recover it, but you can replace it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project) actually explains it very well, but in short you create a dummy workbook with a known password, find some keys in the hex editor and replace the same in your locked workbook with your value from the dummy book.