# How to use VbaDiff to retrieve VBA password?

Tags: excel, password-recovery, vba

Chris Spicer mentioned in an old forum that VbaDiff can be used to retrieve passwords in VBA excel, but he doesn't show how? I am totally lost with the HEX option and I would prefer to use Chris' recommendation, but any one can tell me how?

Warmest regards, and apologies if that had been answered in the past, I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Kindly refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project

Answer (score 0):

VbaDiff doesn't retrieve passwords as such. Because it reads from the VBA document, VbaDiff can read the VBA directly. This is because the code is not encrypted in any way.

This was a surprising side-effect of my approach of not using the Visual Basic Editor.

If you're looking for specific help on VbaDiff, you're probably best to contact me directly. My e-mail address is on my profile.

Regards,

Chris