# packaging excel vba code

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best way to package excel vba code today?
In the past there where stuff like .xll's and .xla's - are those still available ?

When packaged what options do I have for getting this code triggered (i.e. adding a cusotom button / menu item / some for of onLoad event) ?

I am talking about code that when executed results in a self contained workbook being created.
I don't want to code to be a part of every such created workbook.

I would like to know the answer to this for two different situations:
1) When you what the code to NOT be avaiable to the person using it.
2) When you DO want the recipient to be able to edit and modify the code.

another aspect I would like to consider is "does this package get activated/loaded every time the user runs his excel or does he have to intentionally load it from excel ?"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

xla's are still available - at least in Excel 2010, and I imagine in 2013.

An xla can be loaded manually, or can be put in a startup folder to be loaded automatically.

You can password-protect a VBA project to make it more difficult ([but not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)) to edit and modify the code.