# How to enter password in XLS files with python?

Tags: java, python, excel, passwords, xls

So I have a password protected XLS file which i've forgotten the password for...I'm aware it's a date within a certain range so i'm trying to write a brute forcer to try various dates of the year. However, I can't find how to use python/java to enter the password for the file. It's protected such that I can't open the xls file unless I have it and it has some very important information on there (so important I kept the password in a safe place that I now can't find lol).

I'm using fedora. Are there any possible suggestions? Thankyou.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project

Answer (score 0):

If you search there are a number of applications that you can download that will unblock the workbook.

Comment: I had a look but most seem to require windows? Thankyou for the reply :).

Comment: Borrow a Windows computer? But mr.Reband's link has lots of advice.

Comment: Getting a windows computer is a bit difficult at the moment. Is there no way I can simply open xls files with python and enter the password? If I could do that it wouldn't take long at all to write something to brute force the password. There's not too many options, but too many for me to sit and write :P. Thankyou for the reply though, didn't see Mr.Rebands link there.