# how to see the source code in this excel5 .xla file

Tags: excel, xla, vba

I want to know how to open the source code VBA of this file. It is a .xla file and it was created in Excel 5.

https://www.hightail.com/dl?phi_action=app/orchestrateDownload&rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hightail.com%2Ftransfer.php%3Faction%3Dbatch_download%26batch_id%3DOGhkSXQwdkdUME9VbDhUQw&smtNoRedir=1

I have download the convertisseur VBA in order to open it in Excel 2010, but it told me that i need the dll, i dont know which dll it needs and the reference of dll. The menu reference is gray.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the VBA Project password-protected?

Comment: Perhaps, if it is protected by the password, is there some way to see the source code???

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: I have tried, but it did not work ...

Comment: the file is missing VBA project. if it uses external .dll references they are missing and unrecoverable in this case. the only hope is you find the matching dll.