# How to prevent opening an excel if the vba password has been altered

Tags: c#, vba, excel, office-interop

We ship excel workbook with user access control. But, noticed that they can get into the workbook with hex editor approach (via >[Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)) and altering our code to authenticate that user.
To prevent that, we attempted to store DBP = [TEXT] in database and verify against it every time a Macro is launched. It failed as DBP text changes every time the Macro is saved.

Idea is that we try to unlock VBA Project by passing the password that we set and receive a message if the password is correct or not.
Now, the question is, is there a way to automate a process? I found ways to unlock the VBA project via another workbook, but they get stuck if the password is incorrect while automating the process.

The process of verifying can be done server side. So, it would be better if it can be done via C# Office interop rather than VBA. Much better would be OpenXML. VBA solutions are welcomed as well.

Comment: VBA security is for honest people only, to prevent accidental code changes. You are actually out of luck here; move to a different platform if pirating is a problem for you... or use compiled adins (dll, exe, etc.)

Comment: Its more like where to start programing? Goal is to quit macro if the password is tempared. So, you tell me where should i begin.

Comment: If your users can crack your VBA project then there's no point implementing any kind of further security in VBA - that will be easily bypassed.

Comment: What if i disable escape key and kill the application if the password have been altered? Wouldn't that keep them out of the Marco?