# MS Office 2013 - VBA password security

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, ms-office

I am wondering about how safe is the VBA password on MS Office 2013.

I've searched online and there are a bunch of websites selling software to do it, is it reliable?

I want to develop some security around my office files that would depend on the VBA code inside, but if the vba code inside can be easily changed/seen it's non sense going that way.

Thanks

Comment: That depends. How determined do you expect your attacker to be? You'll find this to be interesting. http://superuser.com/q/807926/361752

Comment: I want to know if it's something easy to do, that's my question. Thanks

Comment: Well, take a look at that link and tell me how easy it is? =;)-

Comment: But that I guess is not applicable to office 2013, or is it and I missed something?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the answer, it addresses the newer XML formatted office files. Basically, this is only going to stop your average user from poking around your code. If someone is *attacking* it, they'll get in.

Comment: I tried the last solution for xlsm and it didn't worked out. I get a file corrupt message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this answer as reference : [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Instead of doing all the Hex stuffs. You can try this. It will work for any files (*.xls, *.xlsm, *.xlam ...). Tested and works on Excel 2007, Excel 2010 and Excel 2013 - **32 bit version**.

1. Open the file(s) that contain your locked VBA Projects
2. Create a new xlsm file and store this code in **Module1**

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

   Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
           (Destination As Long, Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

   Private Declare Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As Long, _
           ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flNewProtect As Long, lpflOldProtect As Long) As Long

   Private Declare Function GetModuleHandleA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

   Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, _
           ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

   Private Declare Function DialogBoxParam Lib "user32" Alias "DialogBoxParamA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, _
           ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
           ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer

   Dim HookBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
   Dim OriginBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
   Dim pFunc As Long
   Dim Flag As Boolean

   Private Function GetPtr(ByVal Value As Long) As Long
       GetPtr = Value
   End Function

   Public Sub RecoverBytes()
       If Flag Then MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), 6
   End Sub

   Public Function Hook() As Boolean
       Dim TmpBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
       Dim p As Long
       Dim OriginProtect As Long

       Hook = False

       pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")


       If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

           MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6
           If TmpBytes(0) <> &H68 Then

               MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

               p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

               HookBytes(0) = &H68
               MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(1)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4
               HookBytes(5) = &HC3

               MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 6
               Flag = True
               Hook = True
           End If
       End If
   End Function

   Private Function MyDialogBoxParam(ByVal hInstance As Long, _
           ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
           ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer
       If pTemplateName = 4070 Then
           MyDialogBoxParam = 1
       Else
           RecoverBytes
           MyDialogBoxParam = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, pTemplateName, _
                              hWndParent, lpDialogFunc, dwInitParam)
           Hook
       End If
   End Function
   ```
3. Paste this code in **Module2** and run it

   ```
   Sub unprotected()
       If Hook Then
           MsgBox "VBA Project is unprotected!", vbInformation, "*****"
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
4. Come back to your VBA Projects and enjoy.

P/S: This code is credited to Siwtom (nick name), a vietnamese developer. You could turn this code into an Excel addin for frequently usage.