# Reset Excel VBA password

Tags: vba, excel

I forgets password of one VBA automation developed by me and now I have to update the VBA code but I am unable do that. And also please make note that I don't have permissions to download any application.

Comment: Is the file saved as an xls, xla, or xlam?

Comment: Refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475198/ms-office-2013-vba-password-security). Try using the code it may help you to get the password.

Comment: Nice suggestion

Comment: Hi Mukul need your help for 64 Bit Office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that you can achieve this is by using third party software downloaded from internet, but if you are not allowed to download applications. I say there is no easy way you can crack that vba password without application.

But if you're interested on cracking it. You could try this article:
http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/hack-into-password-protected-vba-projects/
See if it helps.