# How to prevent users from hacking passwords in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, passwords, excel-2007

ON this page: [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project/27508116)
They all talk about hacking the passwords for the macros.
Now how does one prevent that?
I create them where I work and if its this easy then people will be messing with them.

Comment: If there was a way to prevent opening new files in the same Excel instance where your workbook is (essentially forcing only one file per instance), your user would not be able to use the most upvoted answer in that thread, because it works only for files in the same instance. I don't know if it's possible to implement this idea... Other answers basically say that .xslx and .xlsm are safe, as you would not be able to use hex editor on them. However, if you had a really savvy user, you cannot prevent him from opening the code (you can only close some mostly visible doors).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the location, as it'll be harder for hacking
have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I did not see any information on preventing someone from hacking the VBA passwords in the same manor as I posted.