# Is there a way to unprotect an Excel sheet (*xls) using a hex editor?

Tags: excel, password-protection, password-recovery

I was reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project/1038783#1038783), and they describe a method to open a password protected VBA project in excel (V.2003 or .xls). I was wondering if there is a similar method to unprotect excel sheets?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes there is code to unprotect worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Sheet2 is protected by password. Open the workbook. Select sheet2. In vba window of sheet2 paste below codes. Select all codes the run the codes. It will give you a message. Just close message and vba window. Sheet2 is unprotected.

```
    Sub PasswordBreaker()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

        For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
        For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
        For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
        For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
          Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
           Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)

            If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
                MsgBox "One usable password is " & Chr(i) & Chr(j) & _
                Chr(k) & Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & _
                Chr(i3) & Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)
                Exit Sub
            End If

          Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
        Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next

    End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: Come on, what are you posting here!? This code is trying passwords which look like *ABAABABABAAX* and so on (11 times 'A' or 'B' only, plus one additional character at the end)

Comment: Yes it is giving "ABAABABABAAX" But it unprotect my sheet. Do you try? I found it working.