# What are the most effective ways to encrypt and protect my VBScript and VBA code?

Tags: vba, encryption, vbscript, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I need to be able to run my scripts and macros on my client's system without revealing my code. I understand that .vbe wouldn't help much. Is there any way around creating an .exe? But then again, macros would still be exposed. Obfuscate the code?

Would be moving to a python program soon, but until then...

Comment: Moving to Python won't help much. It's still an interpreted language, so it's still relatively simple to reverse engineer. Do note that there are *laws* protecting you from people who would try to steal your code. You don't need to go jump through a bunch of technical hoops that a devoted or knowledgeable hacker could trivially subvert anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I will surely dive a little deeper into this before I begin. I wanted to use python as it would be easier (correct me if i'm wrong) to fetch online content. Do you think using C/C++ would be a better option taking risk/security into consideration?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the VBAproject and click 'Project Properties' then select Protection tab and check 'lock project for viewing' and set a password. Now if anyone wants to view the vba files they need a password first.

Comment: I already do a basic level of protection by converting by .vbs files to .vbe and password protecting my macros. But it's not fool proof, and I was looking for something more secure. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah ok. I've heard CrunchCode is a program you can use to obfuscate the code. But havn't used it myself.

Comment: This is a **very basic** protection of your code. It takes only a few seconds to break it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project