# Is there a way to crack or bypass the VBA project password with Excel 2011 Mac edition?

Tags: macos, vba, excel, password-recovery

There are several good sources (referenced below) that demonstrate how to bypass VBA project passwords for Windows versions of Excel. But, none of these work for Excel 2011 for Mac.

Is there a way to achieve the same result with Excel 2011 for Mac?

References:
[Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

https://superuser.com/questions/807926/how-to-bypass-the-vba-project-password-from-excel

Comment: Send it to someone with a windows PC and ask them to do it? In all seriousness the only way I've seen this done effectively is by using API calls to grab and amend the value of a message being returned to the application. These APIs obviously aren't available for Mac so I'm going to go out on a limb and say it's not possible.