# Protect VBA Project using Excel Add-in

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins, vbe

The requirement is to protect the **VBA Project** of an workbook with password using Excel-Add-in.

> Is this possible?

Currently we have an Excel Add-in (xlam) which does all the operation on each of the workbooks opened. 
We achieved locking of worksheets via Add-in. 
Now we also want to protect the VBA of those opened workbooks. Below is the code which we found from various forums

```
With Application
'execute the controls to lock the project
.VBE.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Tools") _
    .Controls("VBAProject Properties...").Execute
'activate protection
.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
'CAUTION: this either checks OR UNchecks the
'Lock Project for Viewing checkbox, if it's already
'been locked for viewing, then this will UNlock it\
.SendKeys "{ }"
'enter password
.SendKeys "{TAB}" & VBAProjectPassword
'confirm password
.SendKeys "{TAB}" & VBAProjectPassword
'scroll down to OK key
.SendKeys "{TAB}"
'click OK key
.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
'the project is now locked - this takes effect
'the very next time the book's opened...
End With
```

But issue with this code is it protects the VBA of Add-in itself rather than workbook. We need some code or workaround to protect the VBA of workbook via code which will be written in Excel add-in.

Answer (score 0):

That `SendKeys` approach will only ever operate on whichever project is active in the VBE... which may or may not be the add-in project.

The VBIDE API doesn't expose anything to programmatically protect a VBProject, so `SendKeys` *is* the only way - however you should close all opened code windows and activate the host workbook in order to ensure you're hitting the correct target project, as described in [this ozgrid post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13006&p=65776#post65776).

Note that VBA macro protection is [easily defeated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026483/1188513), so it's more of an annoyance for the VBA dev that needs to maintain the project(s) than it is for someone that would want to crack it open: it's a rather symbolic protection, more than anything else.. however VBE add-ins that parse and process the code in the VBE, such as [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (disclaimer: I'm heavily involved with that project) will not parse protected VBA projects, so project protection can be used to boost static code analysis performance.