# How to crack the password for VBA modules in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel 2010 macro enabled workbook for which I have forgotten the password. I tried the method of chaging the file extension to zip and then using the hex editor to change "DPB" to DPx". However when I reopen the xlsm file then excel will repair the workbook and the VBA modules are gone from the file.

Please suggest a way to crack the VBA module password. I used one of the method as per the below link :

[Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted answer in the link you provided?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming-related website. Your question is not about programming. You should post this in https://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just open your excel file with a libre office!!(you can download it for free: 
https://www.libreoffice.org/)
I have tried many times and works fine, open the modules without ask you for a password!!
Copy them and create a new file!!