# how to make VBA password can not unprotect anyhow the business people

Tags: excel, vba

ask for help
how to make VBA password can not unprotect anyhow the business people

I am sorry, my English is not good

Answer (score 1):

This question is too short, but the answer is also short.

The **only way** to guarantee<sup>***†***</sup> that a VBA project password will not be defeated is if you **don't share the file with anyone**.  MS Office is not intended for protecting critically sensitive information or code in shared files.

Not only can the password be removed, but it's *easy*.  I can remove the password on any Office/VBA Project in under a minute. (**[Here's how!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48722078/8112776)**)

<sup>***†***</sup><sub>The claim of *"guaranteed protection by not sharing the file"* assumes that the file in either stored on a device with no network connection, or that your network is "unhackable".</sub>

Comment: There is also code around to do that. When using this code no one will even know that the password was "cracked".

Comment: @Storax It doesn't surprise me that there's code - it's a matter of replacing 3 hex characters with "anything else"... but the easiest way to make sure nobody knows it's "cracked" is to make a second copy of the file, and crack that. :-)

Comment: The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project) I am talking about does not replace anything in the file. It makes Excel "believe" the password was entered without entering it.

Comment: @Storax Tested successfully. very cool (Although I'm always a little nervous about running copy & paste code I don't fully understand... rebooting!)  I'm surprised I didn't notice that before - I have an answer on the same post.