# Excel stops running protected workbook, runs fine if unlocking it

Tags: excel, vba, windows

I have a tool, which uses VBA.

As the tool has company secrets, the project is password protected to avoid the info getting into the wrong hands (to some extent). Therefore, as soon as anyone wants to "view code", they have to put in the password.

The tool has a simple GUI, which just loads values from various worksheets and displays them with simple VBA controls.

In some version updates of the tool, excel stops running when trying to load the GUI. No error codes are displayed. In others, work just fine. I don't know what causes this. The updates are simple changes to formulas, updating of price structuring and the like.

If i put in the password before loading the GUI, it works just fine. This, however, is not a good workaround if i want to deploy the tool to anyone who is not authorized to view the internal info.

Any ideas how to debug this issue?

Windows 10 64-bit
Excel 365
Dell Latitude PC

Comment: Why do you have company secrets in your code in the first place? [The password on VBA projects is trivial to break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026483/4088852). If you have a back-end, let it handle the credentialing. If queries contain proprietary information, put them in views. The *real* problem is that your code has put you in a position where this matters. Fix that instead.

Comment: That is the idea longer term, but the protection will still be used to ensure no changes are made locally. So the protection is used two-fold.