# Unlock VBA in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, forgot-password

Is there a way to unlock password protected VBA in Excel 365?

I am aware of previous solutions like those discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project).
Unfortunately, none of those work anymore in Excel 365 (tested on Mac and Win 64 bit)

Converting to XLS and using the Hex editor approach ends up in errors when I try to open a script. The module tree is visible, but no editors can be opened.
Changing to Zip and working the `vbaProject.bin` results in a file that crashes on load.
The script approach in a second file pretends to work, but Excel crashes when I try to access the VBA.

Comment: In what way does the hex editor approach not work? The file formats haven't changed.

Comment: Are you using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Question is updated with the requested details