# How to crack the password of CATIA vba project using code

Tags: vba, catia

I had written a project using CATIA vba. I m opening this project after lot of time. I have forgotten the password to open the Project. How to crack the password using a code like how we have code in excel vba to crack excel project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it but a quick google search returned this step by step instruction and it looks like people had some luck wit it.

http://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=26511

Comment: Those were my instructions posted on COE.org and on new projects (made using VBA 7 and 7.1 used in recent CATIA versions)  it no longer works. 

If your catvba was made when Catia was using VBA6.x then it will still probably work. 

I have no idea about the excel method linked above.