# How to lock a sheet from being shared?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that converts JSON files to excel and prepares comparison sheets accordingly. It works perfectly fine and its not with the code that I need help. I need to somehow lock the sheet from being shared and used by others.

If I sell this sheet to someone, the sheet should only work in their system can't be copied to others, which will destroy my monopoly market of this sheet.

I want your help to make the excel sheet uniquely work in a few systems only. There could be some way I could use to protect it. Please help with this.

Is there a way to check if the system is connected to a certain wifi network or the pc is connect to a master PC via LAN?

Comment: You cant. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to protect your VBA project from being shared, and making it unique so it only works for whomever you sell it to. However none of these are very reliable, and anyone with a little VBA knowledge could be able to crack it.

To start you could [read out the system](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/see-pc-information-using-simple-excel-vba-script/) to find a unique identifier for the company or person you sold it to, and start your VBA with a test for that exits the sub or kills the sheet if it doesn't find it.

To prevent anyone changing the VBA to bypass this, [password protect your VBA code](https://www.wikihow.com/Protect-VBA-Code) however this isn't very secure due to the way VBA is set up, and [can easily be cracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508116/11936678).

There are possibly more options, for example running the sheet with the VBA from a remote server owned by yourself, and calling it from the sheet every time it's needed, with a unique password that will change every so often. However this would be slow and could be frustrating to work for your client.

Ultimately, you can't 100% protect your VBA projects from anyone with more than basic VBA knowledge.