# Excel password recovery

Tags: excel

I'm trying to open a file protected by password which I don't recall. I've tried the .zip extension method and when I search for sheet protect line in the xml no result appears. So I tried a recovery software which says the file is not encrypted.

When I try to edit a cell it says the file is protected.

What could be the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to open an excel sheet not a VBA project that is protected by a password.

Comment: So, you edit a cell and it says it's protected; that means the worksheet is protected. Have you tried unprotecting it? On the Review tab, click Unprotect Sheet. If it's password protected, it'll prompt you for a password, which is where the linked question will come in handy. If it's not password protected, there's no problem.

Comment: Nothing seems to work from the linked question. What could be the problem here?

Comment: You're gonna need to be more descriptive of the exact issue. You're able to open the workbook, correct? Is the worksheet protected? Is the workbook protected? When you try to update a cell, what exact error message do you get?