# How to remove the password on an MS Access VB Project?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database which contains a password-protected VB Project. The password is unknown. The Access database itself does not have a password, so I can open it: I just can't expand the VB Project tree in the VBE.

If this were Excel, it would be a simple matter. An excellent guide to bypassing an Excel VB Project password can be found right here on Stack Overflow: [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

While the code in the above-referenced answer doesn't appear to be application-specific, I can't get it to work with Access. I believe that this is because in Excel, the same Application object can contain multiple workbooks, and therefore even if one workbook's VB Project is password-protected, you can run this code from modules in a different workbook - and the protection-removal will apply to all workbooks in the Application.

In Access, however, the Application object only holds one current database at a time. I can see no way to open multiple databases in the same Application. What I have tried is to create a new Access VB Project in a fresh Application: insert the password-removing modules as per the Excel answer; then from that VB Project, execute a sub which creates a *new* Access Application, and load the protected database into it - before running the unprotect script. However this didn't work. It seems that the script doesn't work across separate instances of the Application - even if they're both recognised at runtime.

In my work environment I cannot install new software, and have no access to a hex editor. Thus, is there a way to crack the MS Access VB Project password?

### Clarifications

With regards providing code examples, I am a long-time user of Stack Exchange and am intimately familiar with the problem of new users asking questions along the line of "Can you help me?" without actually showing their code: however questions will not always require code to be contained.

If it helps, what I have been trying is as follows:

```
Sub DoVBA()
    Dim app As Application
    Dim filepath As String
    'filepath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CCD-QAF_v0.6.mdb"
    filepath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\CCD-QAF_v0.6_OC2016.accdb"
    '
    Set app = New Application
    app.Visible = True
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase filepath
    unprotected ' Calls sub which works in Excel
End Sub

Sub unprotected()
    If Hook Then
        MsgBox "VBA Project is unprotected!", vbInformation, "*****"
    End If
End Sub
```

.. and then in a different module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
        (Destination As Long, Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As Long, _
        ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flNewProtect As Long, lpflOldProtect As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandleA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, _
        ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function DialogBoxParam Lib "user32" Alias "DialogBoxParamA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, _
        ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
        ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer

Dim HookBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim OriginBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim pFunc As Long
Dim Flag As Boolean

Private Function GetPtr(ByVal Value As Long) As Long
    GetPtr = Value
End Function

Public Sub RecoverBytes()
    If Flag Then MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), 6
End Sub

Public Function Hook() As Boolean
    Dim TmpBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
    Dim p As Long
    Dim OriginProtect As Long

    Hook = False

    pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")


    If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6
        If TmpBytes(0) <> &H68 Then

            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

            p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

            HookBytes(0) = &H68
            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(1)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4
            HookBytes(5) = &HC3

            MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 6
            Flag = True
            Hook = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function MyDialogBoxParam(ByVal hInstance As Long, _
        ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
        ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer
    If pTemplateName = 4070 Then
        MyDialogBoxParam = 1
    Else
        RecoverBytes
        MyDialogBoxParam = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, pTemplateName, _
                           hWndParent, lpDialogFunc, dwInitParam)
        Hook
    End If
End Function
```

The above has been copied from the Excel example in the linked question, which works perfectly in Excel - but does nothing in Access. This is probably because in Excel, you can run this code in one workbook - which acts on all the other workbooks running *within the same Excel application*. However Access only allows one database per application.

Comment: 2 close votes? Please explain why. This question is exactly as topical as the extremely highly-rated Excel question which is linked. I am not asking for software advice: this is about VBA.

Comment: This site https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29074188/remove-forgotten-password-for-vba-on-accdb-file.html (experts exchange - ugh) says _To remove a VBA password, you just open the VBA Editor and click Tools - <Your Database Name> Properties - Protection, and remove the VBA Password from the "Password to view project properties" box._

Comment: @braX - please see edited question.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Thanks, but that's only the standard method to remove a password from a project whose password you *already know*. Did you read my question?

Comment: Every reasonable link I can find on this subject suggests that using a hex editor is the way to go. There are portable hex editors that you can run on your machine without installing [like this one](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/frhed_portable). Instructions for unlocking using the hex editor [can be found here](https://www.devhut.net/2018/05/03/access-unlocking-an-access-vba-project/)  Best of luck!

Comment: @JNevill - Thanks, but no can do. My corporate network is the most restrictive you could imagine. No external USB drives allowed, and any .exe which isn't already part of approved software would be blocked. If I could do this then I would have done already, and would have no need to ask this question.

Comment: Got it. I understand. I've worked in high security environments and they are so restrictive that work just barely manages to get done. I think in this case you are SOL. The only other option I can think of is to roll your own binary to hex type editor in VBA to get into that thing and flip those values. Personally though I would just cut my losses and send that access file to the recycling bin.

Comment: In general, editors and long-time site users discourage meta-commentary in questions. I do understand that questions that are edge-case in on-topic terms can feel unfairly treated, but nevertheless most readers do not sign in or vote, and thus for them, meta-material is just distracting. If you want to vent/discuss about topicality, it is OK in the comments, and it is better in the Meta Stack Overflow site.

Answer (score 1):

just open the .accdb file in HeX-editor directly.
the rest is similar to the Excel instruction.

> Change the DPB=... string to DPx=...

(it must be adjusted in the hex-editor in 3 places, in the excel example only in one place)