# How to iterate pushing ActiveX command button in Excel?

Tags: r, excel, vba, click, activex

I have been given a spreadsheet with an ActiveX control button to execute a complex macro that I can't see the VBA code for because it is password protected. I need to loop through 1000 input values using the ActiveX button. Is there a way to code the part where I click the button in VBA or R?

Here's what I would like to achieve:

1. Set input cell values on SheetA
2. Push a button labeled "RunSimulation" located on SheetA
3. Copy output values on SheetB to a separate table
4. Repeat

I need help with step 2.

Comment: Alternate option: [Crack the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: As convenient as that would be, that would violate the trust of my university collaborator who wrote the password-protected VBA code, and he would likely withdraw his support from our project if we went that way.

Comment: I suggest that since the author is a collaborator, you ask him/her to add the request to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.Run` here, specifying the workbook name, the sheet code module, and the click handler:

```
Dim i as Long
For i = 1 to 1000
    Application.Run "'WorkbookName.xlsm'!Sheet1.RunSimulation_Click"
Next
```

Comment: That gets me closer but now I get the error `"unexpected string constant in "Application.Run " "WorkbookName.xlsm'!SheetA.RunSimulation_Click""`
I tried inserting the full file path before the workbook name as well, and that got the same result.

Comment: Why the extra quotes? Single quote before the workbook name, and only one quote at the end.

Comment: Thank you, this works on a new button I created and has made me realize there are some issues with the button I was originally trying to push that are unrelated to this topic.