# Disable access to a confidential tab

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to send an Excel file to a client with confidential data in the last tab “Use_FeeTR”.
The client should have the ability to change some parameters in the first tabs to run scenarios that will use the confidential tab to calculate some prices, with those prices feeding an output tab for him.
However I don’t want him to see any calculations or info from the last tab.
I did the following:

- Hide the last tab and protect the workbook structure with a password
- OR Hide in VBA environment with xlsSheetveryHidden
- Then protect the cells in the first tabs that are linked to Use Fees so the client cannot see the name of the tab in the formula

It works well, however if he really wants to see the data in the confidential tab, he can still open VBA project, find the name of the tab in **VBA project > Micro Excel Objects**, open a new tab, enter in the first cell `Use_FeeTR!A1` and draw the formulas to see the all values of confidential tab.

Is there a way to hide spreadsheet name in VBA project > Micro Excel Objects? or can I disable VBA for this file (restricting access to VBA project with a password)? I tried to "lock project project from viewing" in VBA Properties but I can still see that tab names in Object list

Comment: After protecting your VBA with a password, access to the object list will be restricted as well. However this does not apply until you save and close the file, and reopen it again. After this, you won't be able to access any VBA attributes of the file without the password.

Comment: Please be aware, that it is extremely trivial to bypass VBA password protection.

Comment: Agreed with @STHOH, all your methods would deter an excel beginner, or someone who doesn't know to look for the sheet. However anyone with more than basic VBA knowledge could easily find a password cracker online. A better way to protect your values would be to store them in an external file somewhere on your clients server where they do not have access to.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1026483) and its answers on how trivial it is. Never, ever, have any confidential information in Excel, ever.