# Worksheet-level macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I have some macros stored in worksheet module in an Excel file.
I protect the whole VBA Project with a password so the code cannot be seen.
But if that worksheet is moved or copied to another workbook, the code becomes visible without any passwords required.
Is there a solution for this?

I am deliberately putting my macros into a worksheet module because I want users to copy this worksheet into their files and work with the macros. But I want to keep them locked for viewing.

Comment: Excel protection is not reliable... especially [project protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project). Maybe create an add-in if you want your code to be secure.

Comment: VBA code is not secure, period. If your code is top-secret, don't write it in VBA. You can lock things down, but it's like putting a padlock on a screen door: most users will play nice and leave it there, but anyone that *wants* can break in relatively easily.