# Is There A Way To Restrict Viewing the VBA Code for Specific Sheets Within A Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

Is There A Way To Restrict Viewing the VBA Code for Specific Sheets Within A Workbook?

I know the common way to "protect" the vba code for a project is go through project properties and set a password.

However, I don't want to password protect the entire VBA project because I want the user to be able to modify the vba code if necessary on particular sheets but not others. Is this possible?

Comment: Regardless, project protection is [basically useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project).

Comment: No not possible unless you separate out the "protected" (see caveat above) code into a separate project (eg as an add-in)