# How secure is MS Excel 2019 .xlsb file format

Tags: excel, security, passwords

Is there any proof that the Excel binary workbook (.xlsb) (especially for Excel 2019) is not secured against VBA password cracking? I'm yet to see a proof. I see mostly topics on other file formats and less of .xlsb

Comment: Which password? A password protecting the file, or a password locking the VBA project? My impression is that the former is secure, the latter not so much.

Comment: I mean a password protecting VBA

Comment: Test it yourself by [cracking it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)... as was mentioned in a comment on your previous question.