# Google Apps Script to open password-protected Excel?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

Is there a way for Google Apps Script to open a password-protected Excel file if the password is supplied when getting the file? I don't see any DriveApp method that accepts a "password" parameter.

If not, then can this be implemented using the Google Drive API? Is there a "password" key I can use in an "options" object of a gapi.client.drive.files.get() or a similar method?

Comment: Probably, with Google App Script you could send 1000000 letters to ask each recipient politely, does he know the password by the way?

Comment: You may try converting it to Google sheets file. I added excel tag... probably excel experts may know a simple/programmatic way to crack/decrypt the file?

Comment: May be related: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483) and [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+password)

Comment: Google Apps Script allows external API... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, that is not possible with Apps Script or Google APIs at this time.

You can always file a feature request in Google's [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) with something along the lines of "Support Excel Password functionality in Drive / Sheets API". From what I could see, there are no existing feature requests for this isssue.

---

The latest news that I could find, that Google have published about password protected files is [this blog post](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2017/02/preview-password-protected-files-in.html), which mentions that now you can **preview** password protected items in Drive.

The guides Google provide [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9406611?hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308757?hl=en) regarding Microsoft Office files detail the functionality that is available. Yet none of it refers to Apps Script, APIs or passwords.

The only possible workaround I can think of is to un-protect them with VBA or other language before they are uploaded to Drive, or send them to an app that can deal with them and send them back (*I know*, that may be painful).