# How to recover VBA Visual Basic password

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have developed an application using VBA access. I forget my module level password. Please guide me how to recover i want to modify the code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to crack the password on an Excel VBA Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: @BigBen:   That's a tie ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your replay sir, but i want to recover access VBA password.

Comment: You can try this, I've never tried it so can't speak for its effectiveness. https://www.devhut.net/2018/05/03/access-unlocking-an-access-vba-project/

Comment: @Warcupine, wow, this worked. But not just any Hex editor. MS Super Hex Editor didn't have text view and search (at least couldn't find how to activate). I used Hex Editor Neo free edition.