# any idea how to deal with excel/vba error 5, the error seems to be connected to VBA but it shows up in recent created excel files even

Tags: excel, vba

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbwve.png)

Every time I open excel with give me that error message, old files or even a new file complete with no VBA no data no nothing yet. And it also pops up when I try to do a simply get data from a EIA add in. Any insights as to how to solve this?

Comment: What is this "EIA" add-in?

Comment: @BigBen Sir, just found this on google search about `EIA` add-in https://www.eia.gov/opendata/excel/

Comment: Also i found there is an error notice given which reads as `Notice: As of February 11th, 2022: The API now only respond to HTTPS. Insecure (HTTP) web protocols are no longer supported.`

Comment: If it's an Excel add-in (xlam), if it's password-protected and you're comfortable [cracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project) the password, you could probably debug further.

Comment: It's either that add-in or a workbook in your `XLSTART` folder.

Comment: If you disable the AddIn, does the error still occur?

Comment: actually the error message appears as soon as I open the file. Any excel file even a new empty one. It just keeps showing if I try to do the add in.

Comment: so the "add in" can't be the problem. @HackSlash how can I check and correct the XLSTARt folder

Comment: @Stela The code would be visible in the VBE. The location is different on each computer. SEE HERE: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-location-of-xlstart-folder-andor/27d80806-7ec0-4d73-934c-6a73d8f4cdbf