# How can I disable view code using macro in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code I tried but it has failed

```
Sub TurnOffViewCode()
   Application.CommandBars("Code").Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just protect your code instead?

Comment: How can I do that using a macro

Comment: Trying to disable viewing code trough VBA is useless because if user deactivates all macros it does nothing. Check [Password protect your VBA project](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2010/06/28/power-tip-password-protect-your-vba-project/)

Comment: Do note that password protecting your vba code is only to keep it safe from dummies, if there's ill intent, they can still get in, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project