# How can I remove password from VBProject?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a problem with a **VB project** that **I d'ont have the password** but I need to open it to check some functions.
I tried to use **"PassWiper For Excel"** but it needs licences key.

I need someone to help me with a tool that **remove the password**, or with a script that do the same thing. Even, if it is possible, if someone can help me with a free licence key of the **"PassWiper For Excel"** .

Thank you for your support

The only tool that I found usufull in **"PassWiper For Excel"** and I watched videos about it and it is the one that I need.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project)

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate - see @Tenior link.