# How to protect more a password-protected Excel Binary Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, binary, password-protection

I have a password-protected Excel Binary Workbook (locked for viewing) that was sent to one of my colleagues. I was so shocked he was able to see all the forms and codes by sending me a screenshot that he has seen them. Now I managed to ask him how he did it and sent me this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

Private Declare Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
        (Destination As Long, Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Declare Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As Long, _
        ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flNewProtect As Long, lpflOldProtect As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetModuleHandleA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, _
        ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function DialogBoxParam Lib "user32" Alias "DialogBoxParamA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, _
        ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
        ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer

Dim HookBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim OriginBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
Dim pFunc As Long
Dim Flag As Boolean

Private Function GetPtr(ByVal Value As Long) As Long
    GetPtr = Value
End Function

Public Sub RecoverBytes()
    If Flag Then MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), 6
End Sub

Public Function Hook() As Boolean
    Dim TmpBytes(0 To 5) As Byte
    Dim p As Long
    Dim OriginProtect As Long

    Hook = False

    pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")


    If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6
        If TmpBytes(0) <> &H68 Then

            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 6

            p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

            HookBytes(0) = &H68
            MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(1)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4
            HookBytes(5) = &HC3

            MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 6
            Flag = True
            Hook = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function MyDialogBoxParam(ByVal hInstance As Long, _
        ByVal pTemplateName As Long, ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
        ByVal lpDialogFunc As Long, ByVal dwInitParam As Long) As Integer
    If pTemplateName = 4070 Then
        MyDialogBoxParam = 1
    Else
        RecoverBytes
        MyDialogBoxParam = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, pTemplateName, _
                           hWndParent, lpDialogFunc, dwInitParam)
        Hook
    End If
End Function


Sub unprotected()
    If Hook Then
        MsgBox "VBA Project is unprotected!", vbInformation, "*****"
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is that, how to protect my whole workbook to avoid my other colleague from opening it again when he uses the code above?

Comment: _"I was so shocked he was able to see all the forms and codes by sending me a screenshot that he has seen them"_ - May I ask why this surprises you?

Comment: IMO, you are wasting your time. Security in Excel is not going to defeat someone who is as determined as that.

Comment: _"My question is that, how to protect my whole workbook to avoid my other colleague from opening it again when he uses the code above?"_ - You can't, and it's an exercise in futility to even try.

Comment: @Dai because i am a newbie and thought that password protection in excel workbook is 100% protecting

Comment: @Dai oh... now i learned something today that it can never be protected. thank you

Comment: The reason it's impossible is because Excel needs to decrypt the file locally, which means Excel needs the private-key, which means Excel can read the entire file just as though it's a normal `.xlsx` file - and Excel runs locally on your computer, so the decryption key must be located somewhere in-memory, it's just a matter of time, patience and skill in order to find it.

Comment: Fun fact: that VBA program in your post came from this very website: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508116/159145