# Excel: Unlock protected sheet forgotten password

Tags: excel, passwords

I stupidly forgot my excel password to unlock the sheet. I'm running Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.12026.20334) 32-bit.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Bryan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cracking Sheet Password with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953979/cracking-sheet-password-with-vba)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad pretty sure that method was patched.

Comment: @Bryan8718 are you able to open the workbook, or is it locked at that level (vs. just locking an individual sheet).

Comment: @MarkS. Yes I can open the workbook, I just can't make any modifications or additions. It is a cash counting document for the till in my shop, and I'd like to add a line to it, but since I've locked everything except for the cells to input cash amounts, I can't make any changes. Thanks for your help

Comment: @bryan8718 depending how you locked it you may be able to copy the data to a different, unlocked sheet and work from there

Comment: @MarkS. Yes, I tried that, but sadly no luck

Answer (score 1):

Open a blank excel workbook.
Now , Try to copy the contents from the sheet that was previously protected and paste it in the blank workbook sheet.
Now try to save this new sheet in .csv format and everything works as it was